# Use existing TLS connection to start Jetty

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

I wonder if it is possible to start a TLS connection via a SSLSocket and pass the existing connection somehow into my embedded Jetty - does anybody know how I can do this?

My current setup allows to start Jetty and to receive HTTP(S) requests. Jetty starts the handshake and I have a successful secured TLS connection. However, I received the requirement to handle it slightly different.
 Jetty shall be started with an already established TLS connection.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your requirement is either bad, or worded poorly.  Starting Jetty after a TLS connection is already established is wrong.  Even handing a already started jetty an already established TLS connection isn't going to work, As there is knowledge about the TLS handshake, SSLEngine, and SSLSession that is a requirement for Jetty (Not to mention the new TLS requirements due to HTTP/2 being introduced)

Comment: Your requirements might be related to SSL/TLS Offloading (usually happening on a proxy/loadbalancer before Jetty).